# Trying to get (p)redis running?

Tags: php, redis

I am trying to get (p)redis running but as soon as i add a set->, it can not connect to redis

```
require "predis/autoload.php";
Predis\Autoloader::register();
try {
  $redis = new Predis\Client();
  $redis->set("hello_world", "Hi from php!");
  $value = $redis->get("hello_world");
  var_dump($value);
  echo "Successfully connected to Redis";
}
```

but it can connect to Redis when

```
require "predis/autoload.php";
Predis\Autoloader::register();
try {
  $redis = new Predis\Client();
  var_dump($redis);
  echo "Successfully connected to Redis";
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Add a `catch` block so you can see what went wrong. The Exception will probably tell you all you need to know.

Comment: `catch (Exception $e) {
   // print_r($e);
    echo $e->getMessage();
}` and i am getting a Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Comment: In both cases? It should be refused on the first case too.

Comment: No my second example code part connects, but the first code example gives the Connection refused. So it seems to refuse as soon as i try to interact with $redis

Comment: That’s because Presis won’t actually connect until you send your first command, so in your second example it’s not actually connected which is why it doesn’t thrown an exception. If you write `$redis->connect()`, it should error out. Is Redis actually on? Is it in localhost? Is it on that port?

Comment: @ishegg you are right! when i write `$redis->connect()` it indeed errors out. I am testing on a localhost (XAMPP ) on a mac. I need to reread the tutorial. I thought Redis was running because `var_dump(($redis));` spits out all functions Tx so far for your time

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: ps: got it to work by Installing Redis `src/redis-server` tx

Comment: Awesome! Good luck.